# Placing form input into an ordered list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-lists

I'm new to javascript. I am trying to grab the answer the user submits through the form and then place it in an ordered list in the HTML document. I know how to do this in PHP but my assignment requires me to use javascript and I'm not sure what to do after I get the element by ID.

Any help is wonderful, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by use get `ElementbyId.value`, then display by `innerHTML`.

```
<textarea placeholder="Type somethings..." id="input"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Change"/>

<div id="result" style="text-align:left"></div>

<script language="javascript"/>
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click',function change(){
        var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=text;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use serializeArray();

Html

```
<form id="testform">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" />
  <input name="bar" value="xxx" />
  <select name="this">
    <option value="hi" selected="selected">Hi</option>
    <option value="ho">Ho</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS

```
function showValues(fields) {
  $( "#result" ).empty().append("<ul></ul>");
  jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
    $( "#result ul" ).append( "<li>"+field.value+"</li>" );
  });
}

$( "#testform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var showfields = $( this ).serializeArray();
  showValues(showfields);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is a fiddle of an example
https://jsfiddle.net/xanfar/sgeuoyhj/

Comment: @AGray, if that code worked for you, accept the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)